# Support for PrimeReact's(version 7.x) Drag and Drop between 2 different Tree Objects

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, treeview, primereact

I already have a [Tree](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact-v7/#/tree/dragdrop) component from PrimeReact 7.x that I use. Now I would like to
have another UI element(another Tree or list my own implementaion) that I should be able to drag and drop to the existing Tree. Preferrable a drag and drop between 2 Tree components since I have a Tree that has drag and drop working with in itself or any alternate solution.

[Codesandbox trial with 2 Tree components failing](https://codesandbox.io/embed/gifted-dijkstra-cc0p2u?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is an open enhancement request(s).

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/2486

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/2615

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/1361

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other good lib you are aware that can help me with this. Thanks

Comment: They may exist but I have no knowledge of any.

Comment: Sorry for all the ques: Is there a way I can enhance PrimeReact TreeView to have what I am looking for? and how? :-)

Comment: I would say study the code and submit a pull request to one of the tickets above if you get it working.